# creating watermark in pdf's created with dompdf's php5 class

Tags: php, watermark, dompdf

Is it possible to place a watermark into a PDF generated by the dompdf's php5 class?

If yes; how do I do it?

If no; is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in example [demo_01.html](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php#test/demo_01.html,pdf) (at the bottom of the page)

```
<script type="text/php">
   $pdf->open_object();
   $w = $pdf->get_width();
   $h = $pdf->get_height();
   $pdf->close_object();
   $pdf->page_text(110, $h - 240, "DELETED", Font_Metrics::get_font("verdana", "bold"),110, array(0.85, 0.85, 0.85), 0, -52);
</script>
```

this will add a big 'DELETED' string over your document